# Having issues combining two var into one if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Just getting started with coding and having trouble visualizing how to write this code:

```
var userAge = prompt("Are you old enough to vote? Lets check, enter your age.","");
        var citizen = prompt("Are you a US citizen? Y or N","");

        if(citizen = y && userAge >= 18)  
        {
            alert("Congrats, you can vote!");
        }else
        {
            alert("Sorry you can vote just yet");
        }

        document.write("<br/>");

        if(citizen = n && userAge < 18)
        {
            document.write("but at least you have your youth");

        }else if (citizen = y && userAge > 18)

            {
            document.write("You should be registered to vote! If not, visit www.usa.gov/register-to-vote");
            }
```

Any insights?  Thanks for your time and support.

Comment: How about you explain what it is you want the code to do and what, ***specifically*** you are confused about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For comparison `==` or `===` is used. `=` is used for assignment.
2. When the user inputs, their input will be recorded as a string. Assuming that they will only respond with an upper-case `'Y'` or an upper case `'N'` your code should be something like:

---

```
var userAge = prompt("Are you old enough to vote? Lets check, enter your age.", "");
var citizen = prompt("Are you a US citizen? Y or N", "");

if (citizen === 'Y' && userAge >= 18) {
  alert("Congrats, you can vote!");
} else {
  alert("Sorry you can vote just yet");
}

document.write("<br/>");

if (citizen === 'N' && userAge < 18) {
  document.write("but at least you have your youth");
} else if (citizen === 'Y' && userAge > 18) {
  document.write("You should be registered to vote! If not, visit www.usa.gov/register-to-vote");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just the help I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You have some redundancies in your code (in that you have a couple places where you check if both citizen is y and age > 18 (although in one spot you check >=). However, the biggest issues I'm seeing is that you don't have your string values in quotes and you need to be using the == operator as your comparison operator. A single = operator is the assignment operator to assign a value to a variable.